# Pigeonhole Principle Question - Selecting some items from a box that contains fifty items with different colors

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Please help me understand this question. I got the answer 101, however it says the solution to this question is 11. Perhaps it was a typo?

Suppose you select some items from a box that contains fifty items, where there are ten each of the colors blue, red, green, yellow, and purple. How many items must you select to make sure that you get at
least three of the same color?

As requested, I will express the problem and my thoughts. Note that ceiling division is used in this problem. I will denote ceiling division with the symbols [x], and I will use <= for less than or equal to.

3 <= [X/50]

2 < X/50

100 < X

101 <= X

This is how my discrete structures professor requested how I complete this problem.

Comment: The answer is correct. Note that 101 doesn’t seem very reasonable considering that there are only 50 items to begin with.

Comment: Why not tell everybody your thoughts about this question? A single answer is not helpful to you. People would be glad to check your reasoning and tell you which part is wrong. Please add your thoughts in the post, not in the comment section.

Comment: It's $2 < \frac{X}{5}$ and $3 \leq \left\lceil \frac{X}{5} \right\rceil$.

Comment: Please [edit] the title of the question into something more descriptive.

Comment: I think you read the question wrong: there are 10 items for each color, i.e. 10 blue, 10 red, 10 green, 10 yellow, and 10 purple.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the bins, one for each color. Keep putting the marbles in the binary color. If we got two for each color, that would be  5 * 2 = 10 marbles. The next marble,regarldess of color, would make one of the bins contain 3 marbles. Yes by chance we could use fewer marbles, but 11 is the worst case scenario.

This is the essence of the pigeonhole principle. The bins are the pigeonholes and, we see how we can fill the pigeonholes **without** the condition holding. Then we add one more object to obtain the solution.

Comment: I am not sure this is a clear answer to how the 101 was calculated.